# How to replicate ten databases tables in single database using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

We are using MYSQL in that we have 10 databases as single project.
my problem is to auto-merge 10 database tables into single database using replication.

> for example  :
>   **MasterDatabases**
>
> **database1**
>    ....table1
>    ....table2
>
> **database2**
>    ....table21
>    ....table22
>
> **database3**
>     ....table31
>     ....table33
>
> **Replication Database**
>
> **slavedatabase**
>      ....table1
>      ....table2
>      ....table21
>    ....table22
>      ....table31
>      ....table33

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--replicate-rewrite-db` for that.

> Tells the slave to create a replication filter that translates the
>   default database (that is, the one selected by USE) to to_name if it
>   was from_name on the master. Only statements involving tables are
>   affected (not statements such as CREATE DATABASE, DROP DATABASE, and
>   ALTER DATABASE), and only if from_name is the default database on the
>   master. To specify multiple rewrites, use this option multiple times.
>   The server uses the first one with a from_name value that matches. The
>   database name translation is done before the --replicate-* rules are
>   tested. You can also create such a filter by issuing a CHANGE
>   REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB statement.

Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db).

Comment: Thanks fancyPants,  Actually i'm new to database replication can u give any sample links which is used same scenario.